# Elasticsearch Space independent search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elasticsearch instance setup with default index. 10000's of text document has been indexed in them and I want to perform space independent query. I want to perform searches like below cases.

**Case 1 space in index no space in query:**

```
 index data : 123 456 43
 query data :12345643
```

**Case 2 space in query no space in index:**

```
 index data : 12345643
 query data : 123 456 43
```

As you can see above query will not since query data is one term and index data is three terms. Vice-versa for case 2

**Case 3 partial matches with space difference:**

```
 index data : 12345643
 query data : 123 4 5
```

**Case 4 partial matches with additional data(trailing/leading) and space difference:**

```
 index data : 12345643
 query data : 123 4 54

 index data : 1234564343
 query data : 123 4 5
```

I thought of creating a index with space removed and index complete content as one word but I don't know how it would work for case3 and case4. I also don't know the fallbacks of this method.

Comment: I would remove spaces and create a custom analyzer with (edge-)ngrams.

Comment: Thanks val I will try it and let u know. Will that also match for case 3 and 4 with additional data either in the index or query.

Comment: Yes, if you use edge-ngram at search time as well you can match prefixes and suffixes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove spaces and create a custom index-time analyzer with ([edge-](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html))[ngrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) (either tokenizer or token filter).

You can also use an edge-ngram tokenizer/token-filter at search time if you want to match prefixes and suffixes.